# Rearranging worksheet layout by script execution to conform to sql import process

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, layout, import

over the time I've been building a quite huge database in excel that now I would like to transfer onto a more classic mysql database for operative reasons, since I need to be able, among other things, to display this *footage* on a web page.
The problem is that in my opinion my sheet's layout doesn't fit seamlessly with a typical db table, causing some "compatibility" issues in the import process.

Please have a look at the following screens to see what I mean:
[image]

The above is my typical spreadsheet layout where, as you can see, additional pieces of information is written into a **new row**, ***not*** into an **adjacent cell**.

While this is on the other hand what I believe it should look like to perfectly fit into an import process for a sql table (correct me if I am wrong):
[image]

Now, my question is: 
given that the amount of rows is so big that I cannot perform this operation manually and given that my assumptions are valid, which is the best way to carry on this rearrangement?

Is it better to perform the rearrangement in excel and then import the data into mysql or
mysql import process is already providing some tools to make this happen?

Clearly I would prefer the first option because it gives me the possibility to verify the process before importing, but I would need a help *code-side* anyway to be able to do that.

What's your opinion on this?
thanks

Comment: My opinion is first layout is better.

Comment: How would you import the data to your database? is it via code or connecting excel directly to the database? Answer is probably dependent on how you will transfer data to the database

Comment: @Zac I don't think I can connect excel directly to the Db, since it's an older version (2007). What I usually do and was thinking doing the same this time as well is exporting the excel sheet into a csv, laying out a table in mysql with the exact corresponding fields and finally importing the csv via the import section within phpmyadmin. But of course I will adapt if you provide me a more "correct" way to do this. thanks

Comment: @P.Salmon what do you mean, can you elaborate? thanks

Comment: As you already have your data in your workbook, you could just write some VBA code to grab your data and add it directly to your SQL database. You don't need to convert to csv and then import. This way, you don't have to change the format of your data in your workbook. There are many examples of VBA code on the net that will show you how to connect to the database and use `Insert` query to add data to your database

Comment: @Zac thanks I'll look that up and in case get back here